# How to assign a value to a variable and also check its value in a while loop?

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, variable-assignment

I'm doing a time-critical application in C. I want to assign a value to a variable and check its value at the same time in a while loop to reuse it later in the body of this loop. The value assigned to the variable is returned by a function that takes some time to run. I know I can do something like that:

```
while (function_returning_int() <= foo) {
    bar(function_returning_int());
}
```

The problem is that this involves calling the same function two times. I tried doing that instead:

```
while ((int thing = function_returning_int()) <= foo) {
    bar(thing);
}
```

It gives me an error. I don't understand why since the assignment operator (`=`) returns the assigned value. How can I assign a value to a variable and check its value at the same time in a while loop?

Comment: Short C code does not mean faster execution, regardless of whether shortness is measured in characters of source code, lines of source code, or number of operations in C code. Understanding how source code affects performance in modern systems requires deep understanding of compilers, processors, and other technologies. As you develop that, prefer to write clear code rather than code with “clever tricks.”

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're close. You just need to declare the variable outside of the loop:

```
int thing;
while (( thing = function_returning_int()) <= foo) {
    bar(thing);
}
```

Comment: Too bad `auto` cannot be used for such loops. Background: I have a function returning an `std::chrono::duration` ("time remaining"), and ideally I would use the very same type it returns, which is `milliseconds` right now, but maybe later could change to `microseconds` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the result in a variable. To limit its scope one can use c99 syntax for 'for' loop.

```
for (int val; ( val = function_returning_int()) <= foo;)
    bar(val);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead. solution is assign value of variable which is declared inside the loop to another local variable.and then use variable in main method.declare the variable outside the while loop.